# Does Facebook Profile user id change?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to convert the facebook profile url to the user id using the findmyfbid.in. My question is that whether the returned user id changes over time or remains the same, since this id is not an app scoped id.

Comment: Why are you using findmyfbid.in? What use do you have of that ID?

Comment: learn about app scoped ids. do not use findmyfbid - that platform scrapes the profile, which is not allowed and there is no use for the resulting id. also, fql is gone since many years, so why use that tag?

Comment: then is using findmyfbid illegal ?